# Code Cleanup using ReSharper in Razor template doesn't wrap

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

When I reformat my razor templates (cshtml files) using ReSharpers Code Cleanup feature, it doesn't respect the maximum line length and simply puts each instruction on one line. Even when that results in lines that are 200 characters long.
The C# files (.cs) are formatted properly.

Am I missing a setting?

Update:

I have set my line limit to 120:
[image: Resharper Settings]

And I am talking about code like this:

[image: Code sample]

If I reformat that, it will all be on one line that is 230 characters long.

Comment: I can't seem to duplicate this behavior but probably because I am not sure what you have in your razor template. Can you post an example of what you mean by `instruction`? Do you have a c# code block `@{}` with something in it or is it when you reference a helper like `@Html.` or maybe something else entirely? Also are you using the latest version of r#? Finally question, is your 200 char limit set in `Resharper -> Options -> (Code Editing) C# -> Formatting Style`? I do not see any options in either Html or Razor for char limits.

Comment: @Igor I updated my question. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: I do not think the c# formatting styles will be used as you are in a razor view so technically not a `*.cs` file. However, I still cannot duplicate this behavior and am using R# version `2016.1.2`. What version are you using? Are there any HTML or Razor formatting styles you are using?

Comment: @Igor: I am using 2016.1. My Razor, ASP.NET and HTML settings look normal, I don't see anything that corresponds to this. Is your Resharper reformatting the Razor code at all?

Comment: Indeed, I am using Code Cleanup (ctrl+alt+f), see the following [link for screenshot](http://imgur.com/fAHhsnC). Is this what you are doing or is this automatic reformatting when you close a block using `)` or `}`?

Comment: @Igor: I am using Code Cleanup as well... Really strange

Comment: You can export the settings you having under `Options` -> `Manage...` -> `Export to file` and make that available. I (or who ever) can then compare this to see what is different in your setup.